# NuGet private server returns 502 (Bad Gateway) when pushing new package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-server, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

I deployed new private NuGet server (NuGet.Server.3.4.1) and set up API key in web.config.

Then I created first nuget package from my .net core class library project.

But when I try to run following command

`dotnet nuget push packageName.1.0.0.nupkg --api-key myKey --source https://privateNugetServer.com/nuget`

I get an error from the server

> error: Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad
> Gateway).

I tried workaround when I uploaded package manually with Nuget server itself, but than I still got this error when I add additional Package source to visual studio nuget manager pointing to my server.

> error: Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad
> Gateway).

What might be an issue ?

Comment: How long does it take for error to occur.  You may be going to a proxy server and the net library waits 30 seconds to timeout waiting for a response from the proxy. Did code ever work? When did it stop working?  Five years ago industry decided to stop using TLS 1.0/1.1 for authentication and instead use TLS 1.2/1.3.  Microsoft pushed a security update in June for servers to disable TLS 1.o/1.1.  If a client is still using TLS 1.0/1.1 an error will occur.  So you may still be using old TLS.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and verify version of TLS

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The nuget server (website) is brand new, so it has no working history yet. The error occure immediately. The connection use `TLS 1.2, AES with 256 bit encryption (High); ECDH with 255 bit exchange` so it should be ok, but there might be an issue with corporate proxy. I don't know yet, but I will investigate it further.

Comment: Do you need the proxy?  Does server want TLS 1.3 instead of 1.2? I've seen a case this week where TLS worked and TLS 1.2 failed.  Does query work in Postman?  If so, you can compare the Postman and c# to see differences.

Comment: I forgot about this question. But I think the reason was the corporate proxy and we had to allow the Azure DevOps URL. I think the proxy decrypted the request and encrypted it again and that invalidated the certificate chain and the server threw an error.

Answer (score 1):

For Artifactory users: An error code of 502 (bad gateway) for a `nuget push` can have different reasons. According to [this issue](https://jfrog.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/RTFACT/issues/RTFACT-23806/?filter=allissues) it can be related to permissions.

Another reason can be this: I was able to deploy a NuGet package via Artifactory Web UI, but a `nuget push` did not work. I did provide credentials when I added the repo with `nuget sources Add`, but I did not set an API key with `nuget setapikey`. After also setting the API key, I was able to upload a package with `nuget push`.